# Communicate child processes without pipe,dup and fifo

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

The program is forking, every child can be father then like grandfather. I want to communicate them by using a text file. They will read the number, sum up every time with prior one then write back to the file. I write `0` at first on the text file with `open()` in read-write mode. Afterwards, in a function call the code,

```
int sum = 0;
lseek(fd, 0, 0);
read(fd, &sum, sizeof(sum));
sum = sum + count;
write(fd, &sum, sizeof(sum));
```

All child go in the function but as a result always gotten `0`. I have printed `count` values, get rightly. I have also tried to lock to syncronize(`fcntl()`) them but not succeed.

Comment: Since you `fork()`. It does not block the parent and both the child and parent run parallel. maybe before a process modifies the file, all the other threads have already read the file. This scheduling is done by the kernel and you cannot change it. You can use `vfork()` if you want the parent to be suspended till the child modifies the file.

Comment: Be very cautious with `vfork()`; in the classic version, you can only exec or exit.

Comment: You really need to show an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It is fairly likely the synchronization problem identified by @SurajS.  There are many IPC mechanisms other than pipes that could be used. We can't tell which ones you're aware of and which might be appropriate to suggest.

Comment: I'm aware of socket, shared memory, named pipe, pipe, message queues. But I don't want to use them at this level. gradually wanna apply them. Think of a directory and includes text files, maybe dir in another dir, I count the words and sum up the total as a result. But, every file belongs to a child. Everything is okay except summation part. As I said every child runs the snippet into. Since I check pids, it's forking as intended. The issue is about managing them. I'm just using the snippet to the sum part. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: By the way, I can open files for every child to save counted number with their pids then read files and sum the values from the parent but it seems long for me. I'm thinking easy way without the IPCs. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: You're working with communicating processes; you can't avoid using IPC (inter-process communication).  Can the parent wait for the children to die?  Could child N (0, 1, 2, …) write to position N in the file, so the parent reads the whole file as an array once the children complete and then sums it?

Comment: _Can the parent wait for the children to die?_ -> of course, otherwise isn't it _zombie_? Shouldn't the parent always wait for its kids? I think the parent always should wait.  _Could child N (0, 1, 2, …) write to position N in the file, so the parent reads the whole file as an array once the children complete and then sums it?_ Yes it is possible. It's another good solution seemingly. But, can't we go with my code snippet? And what about _flock_? Can't we apply it on the snippet? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Note that your snippet reads the first four bytes and writes the second four bytes.  Do you simply need to seek back to the start before writing?  You'd need to seek backwards one unit if treating the file as an array.  Note that treating the file as an array is a simple form of synchronization.  Each child works on its part and leaves every one else's part alone.

Comment: I'm using for backward lseek, did I misunderstand what you mean? Frankly, I don't want to share my all code here, but I want you to inform me with your knowledge as well because I've spent too much time for it.  [This link](http://sonerakar.com.tr/soner_code.txt)  is all my code. To answer your explanation, yes I want to do what you mean as array I think. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: You do a seek before you read; once you've read, you need to do another seek to overwrite what you read.  If you treat the file as an array, then child N will seek to `lseek(fd, N * sizeof(int), SEEK_SET)` before reading, and `lseek(fd, -sizeof(int), SEEK_CUR);` before writing.  After you read, the current position is after the last byte read; if you immediately write, the write goes there, after the data you read.  (Beware: standard I/O with `FILE *` streams mandates seeks or similar between reading and writing or vice versa on a stream for update.  File descriptor I/O does not.)

Comment: OMG! It's worked when I put lseek before write(). But how come how why ? What about syncronazation? Don't I need flock ? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: You can use any synchronization technique you like.  `flock()` is one; `fcntl()`, `locking()`, `lockf()` are other locking options which may be available.  Etc.

Comment: A dead child is a zombie until orphaned by the death of the parent (whereupon a system process inherits the orphan and waits for it and it ceases to exist at all), or until the parent waits for (acknowledges) the child's death (and it ceases to exist at all).

Comment: But, I wonder _isn't `write()` function automatically cleaning and overwriting the file?_ However, It's not in append mode, it's just writing. For locking mechanism, when a child locks the common file to read-write, there will be dead lock. I mean once a child obtains lock, the another one also want to obtain it? How can I prevent/avoid from it? How can I block the other children up to releasing the lock? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Unless the file is opened in append mode, the `write()` function writes at the current position in the file; the `read()` function reads from the current position in the file.  If one child locks the file descriptor, seeks, reads, seeks, writes, unlocks, no other child can do anything with the file while the first child holds the lock — as long as the other child also pays attention to the locks.  If the children ignore the locks, then all bets are off, but if they're dutiful obedient children and play by the rules and not wild anarchistic renegades, then all will be well.

Comment: I will strive for the synchronization. Thank you for your education for me. I hope I can take advantage of your training again whether I stuck or not. You must be alive version of Dennis Ritchie!  @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @concurrencyboy btw, I found the book you copied the concurrency code from in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588250/reuse-the-variable-passed-to-as-thread-paramater) and I think you could actually make it into a useful self-qa if you mention the source etc, then write an answer to it yourself and self-accept and ping me, I could upvote. As it was written now I didn't realize it was copied verbatim